# Where can i find the Ubuntu-touch 14.04 changelogs

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am trying to find the changelogs for the Ubuntu touch 14.04 dailys builds.
Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so here is what I wanted. Someone from canonical on IRC #ubuntu-touch provided it. With the comment that that link isn't to be treated as a 'stable' channel. I guess its mostly meant for Canonical employees. Still, its usefull to me for testing purposes, so I thought I'd share:

[people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/changes/](http://people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/changes/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the manifest for the [latest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/trusty-preinstalled-touch-armhf.manifest) and the [pending](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/pending/trusty-preinstalled-touch-armhf.manifest) daily-preinstalled image. You can also find other daily images [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/).

Comment: cheers, Although really I was hoping for something that specified just what are the changes between the builds. (I just deployed 14.04 r70, I think) Manifests contain everything thats in that build. But I guess thats as good as its gets :)

Comment: That is the closest I got to. You can always compare two manifests. Sure that is a lengthy way.

Comment: Yep, you got my problem. Plus, I think if packages are in both, but the content is changed, you can't even tell can you? From the Manifest that is

Comment: There you are. Is that because its still not public?

Comment: No, dont thinks so. I'll try asking on irc just to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: good luck for that

Comment: Eureka! And they say irc is dead.. got a link. I'll post it in a separate answer soo its easier to find for future questions.